# Sending Email via Exchange Web Services Asynchronously

Tags: asynchronous, exchangewebservices

Our Web solution (Web Role hosted on Azure) currently sends emails via Office 365 using Exchange Web Services leveraging the `SendAndSaveCopy` method of a `MSExchange.EmailMessage`.

Is it possible to do this as a Async Task?

NOTE: The full refactor will queue the mail messages and have a worker role action them but I was curious as to whether EWS also had Async options for sending email as all my research has come up blank.